# Why are my bootstrap classes not working correctly?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my main index.html, I reference bootstrap CSS, but styles are not being resolved correctly?

In my  [test site](http://writers-tryst-test.ron-tornambe.com/#/) I have defined a `<p class="bg-warning">Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.</p>`, but it does not show the warning colors.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" data-ng-app="wtApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
        <title>Writer's Tryst, where authors and publishers, producers, agents meet.</title>
        <meta name="description" content="A better way for writers to find publishers, producers and agents" />
        <link  href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two:700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="frainversegment" content="!" />
        <meta name="google-site-verification" content="yVui_k1sbN4TDHx-yDmol0MzU1QXaTTGlhNa_gVLzUs" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" data-integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" data-crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" data-integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" data-crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/shares.css" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/icons/writers-tryst.png" />
<!--
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
              document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            try {
                var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-15499108-1");
                    pageTracker._trackPageview();
                } catch (err) { }
        </script>

        <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>

        <script>
            (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
              google_ad_client: "ca-pub-3982825388677642",
              enable_page_level_ads: true
            });
        </script>
-->
    </head>
    <body data-ng-controller="mainController">
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Writers-Tryst">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo" src="img/writers-tryst-logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Writers-Tryst">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a id="homepage" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#writers" class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"> Writers</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#enablers" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"> Enablers</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#about" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"> About</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#privacy" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"> Privacy/Rules</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#contact" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"> Contact</a></li> 
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#log-in"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i> Log-In</a></li> 
                            <li><a id="create-account-link" href="#accounts"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Create Account</a></li> 
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" id="drop-toggle-1" class="dropdown-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-user" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-aria-haspopup="true" data-aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a id="update-profile" href="#update-profile">Update profile</a></li>
                                    <li><a id="manage-uploads" href="#manage-uploads">Manage uploads</a></li>
                              </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li ><a id="reset-pwd-link" href="#reset-pwd"></a></li> 
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
<!--
            <div class="google-ad-top">
                <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
                <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                        style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
                        data-ad-client="ca-pub-3982825388677642"
                        data-ad-slot="1133448516"></ins>
                <script>
                    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                </script>
            </div>
-->
        </header>
        <p class="bg-warning">Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.</p><br/>

        <div id="shares">   
            <!-- Twitter -->
            <a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=writers.tryst.ron-tornambe.com&text=<TEXT>&via=<VIA>" target="_blank" title="twitter" class="share-btn twitter">
                <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
            </a>

            <!-- Google Plus -->
            <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=writers.tryst.ron-tornambe.com" target="_blank" title="google+" class="share-btn google-plus">
                <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
            </a>

            <!-- Facebook -->
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://writers.tryst.com" target="_blank" title="facebook" class="share-btn facebook">
                <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
            </a>

            <!-- StumbleUpon (url, title) -->
            <a href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=http://writers.tryst.com&title=<TITLE>" target="_blank" class="share-btn stumbleupon">
                <i class="fa fa-stumbleupon"></i>
            </a>

            <!-- Reddit (url, title) -->
            <a href="http://reddit.com/submit?url=http://writers.tryst.com&title=<TITLE>" target="_blank" class="share-btn reddit">
                <i class="fa fa-reddit"></i>
            </a>

            <!-- LinkedIn -->
            <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url=http://writers.tryst.com&title=<TITLE>&summary=<SUMMARY>&source=<SOURCE_URL>" target="_blank" title="linked-in" class="share-btn linkedin">
                <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
            </a>

        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="message" class="alert m-t-10"></div>
            <div id="main" class="content">
                <!-- angular templating -->
                <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
                <div data-ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div>&#169; 2016 Ronald Tornambe, Inc.</div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/common.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="js/pages.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("#drop-toggle-1").on("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            $("#update-profile").on("click", function () {
                sessionStorage.setItem("create-or-update", "update");
                console.log("session-storage=" + sessionStorage.getItem("create-or-update"))
                $("#create-account-link").trigger("click");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This won't necessarily solve your problem, but I would recommend not referencing both the normal and minimized bootstrap files. If you open Firebug for your 'test site', you'll see that all bootstrap declarations are duplicated because you're effectively including bootstrap twice.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Bootstrap documentation (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-backgrounds), your warning paragraph is showing the correct color. It looks a little different because you're missing the padding - Bootstrap has a `padding: 15px` attribute by default.